# cardinal components to cardinal direction using arctan function

Tags: matlab, angle, atan2

I have ocean currents data (going towards). what would be the conversion I can use?

270-(atan2(zonal,meridional)(180/pi)) or 270-(atan2(meridional,zonal)(180/)) or anything entirely different?

I have gone through [this link][1] and also [eol][2] website. I still have no idea.

using unit circle and arctan function I tried to do, like for first quadrant **zonal component(x)** towards **east-west** is **positive** and **meridioanl** **component**(y) **north-south** is **positive** I used arctan(x,y) to find the direction.

then for 2nd quadrant 90+arctan(x,y) ???

3rd quadrant 180+arctan(x,y) ??

4th quadrant 270+arctan(x,y) ??

please correct me if I am wrong...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what are you exactly asking, but the function `atan2` already gives you the correct quadrant, so no special tricks must be done adding or substracting angles to the result.

If you write `help atan2` you will see that it expects two parameters: `y` and `x` (in this order) and returns you an angle in `radians` with a range `[-pi,+pi]`

Eg.

`rad2deg(atan2(1,1))`   gives you 45 as result

`rad2deg(atan2(-1,1))`   gives you -45 as result

`rad2deg(atan2(1,-1))`   gives you 135 as result

`rad2deg(atan2(-1,-1))`   gives you -135 as result

EDIT:
if you want only positive angles, just do:

```
angle = atan2(Y, X);
if (angle < 0)
    angle = angle + 2*pi;
end
```

Comment: yes I used atan2(u,v) in matlab. once after getting the results if the degrees are less than zero added up to 360 (negative degrees)..

Comment: Good, so what's the question exactly?

Comment: I think angle = atan2(X, Y) rather atan2(Y, X) since I am using cardinal coordinate system here X means East-West component (90 - 270 degrees) Y means North-south component (0 - 180)

Comment: `atan2` considers the angles starting in the direction west-east (vector(1,0)) and increasing anticlockwise.
Rather than swapping X and Y (which can be confusing) I would rather modify the output angle of `atan2` to fit your custom coordinate system.